# How do I input random numbers in C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;
int randBetween()
{
    
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    
    const int MIN_VALUE = -100;
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
    
    return (rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1 )) + MIN_VALUE;
}




int main() {
   
    const int SIZE = 10;
    
    int myArray[SIZE];
    
    
    // ^^ how do I use function above to give myArray random values?
    
    return 0;
}
```

I wanna use that rand function to give my array random values from -100 to 100 but I dont know how to put that rand function in the array so that my array can generate random number inside it hopefully that makes sense how do I do that?

Comment: You will need to do it in a ***loop***.

Comment: seed only once, and prefer [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) facility over `srand`/`rand`.

Comment: Consider using [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate), e.g., `std::generate(begin(myArray), end(myArray), randBetween);`.

Comment: general advice: Do/Learn one thing at a time. Do you know how to assign any values to the array elements? Do you know how to generate random numbers? (your code doesnt do that properly) Only if you got each of them you should put them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll take a look at your code and critique it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
// MISSING <cstdlib> for C random functions

using namespace std;  // Bad Practice
int randBetween()
{
    
    unsigned seed = time(0);  // Wrong placement; should only instantiate ONCE
    srand(seed);
    
    const int MIN_VALUE = -100;
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
    
    return (rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1 )) + MIN_VALUE;
    // Modulo math tends to make the values in the lower end of the range more prevalent; i.e., 
    // it's not very uniform.
}




int main() {
   
    const int SIZE = 10;  // All caps names for constants is not desirable; they can be confused for macros
    
    int myArray[SIZE];  // Prefer std::array if the size is known, else std::vector for most cases
    
    
    // ^^ how do I use function above to give myArray random values?
    
    return 0;
}
```

The biggest issue is the use of C-style conventions when C++ provides better methods. In fact, you won't even need a function for this.

The secret sauce of getting the random numbers into your array is a loop. Make your loop visit every element and assign a new random number. Either directly, as in my first example, or by using a function as in my second example.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
  const int minValue = -100;
  const int maxValue = 100;
  const int size = 10;

  std::array<int, size> myArray;

  // std::mt19937 is the goto PRNG in <random>
  // This declaration also seeds the PRNG using std::random_device
  // A std::uniform_int_distribution is exactly what it sounds like
  // Every number in the range is equally likely to occur.
  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(minValue, maxValue);

  for (auto& i : myArray) {
    i = dist(prng);
  }

  for (auto i : myArray) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Now, if you want or need the function, there's a little bit of extra work that needs to be done.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int randBetween() {
  const int minValue = -100;
  const int maxValue = 100;

  // The keyword static is required now so that the PRNG and distribution
  // are not re-instantiated every time the function is called. This is
  // important for them both to work as intended. Re-instantiating resets
  // their state, and they constantly start from scratch. They must be allowed
  // to persist their state for better results.
  static std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());  // Note the static
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(minValue, maxValue);

  return dist(prng);
}

int main() {
  const int size = 10;

  std::array<int, size> myArray;
  for (auto& i : myArray) {
    i = randBetween();
  }

  for (auto i : myArray) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Separating the PRNG from the distribution is good practice, especially when programs get larger. Then your single PRNG can feed multiple distributions if needed.

One output that I got:

```
-2 -37 81 85 -38 -62 31 -15 -12 -31
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolling up the comments into an answer:

You could use a loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    myArray[i] = randBetween();
}
```

Or you could use the standard algorithm [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
std::generate(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), randBetween);
```

This will loop over the array, calling `randBetween` for each member and assigning it to the result.

You have a big issue, however. [You should not call `srand` each time you want a random number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/10077). Call it *once*, in the beginning of `main`. As you have it now, you will likely fill the array with one number for a given run. There is a tiny chance the number will change part way through the array if the second of the current time changes during the program run.

Also the [C++ Standard Library for random numbers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) is much preferable to `rand`. And I'd recommend using [a standard container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) rather than a native array.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!

Comment: It would be better if you also showed the standard way of generating random numbers using standard library features.

Comment: @digito_evo: I'd rather focus my answer on what is being asked. `rand` works, though it's not ideal, and there is good example code in what I linked.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate way would be to use PRNG(Pseudo Random Number Generator). This is from the include random, include functional header. Like this, run this in C++17 compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional> // For std::bind()


auto createUniformPseudoRandomNumberGenerator(double max)
{
 std::random_device seeder; 
 std::default_random_engine generator{seeder()};
 std::uniform_real_distribution distribution{0.0, max};
 return std::bind(distribution, generator); 
}

int main() 
{

const int SIZE = 10;

int myArray[SIZE];


double limit{};
std::cout<<"Enter max number limit.\n";
std::cin>>limit;

static auto random_number=createUniformPseudoRandomNumberGenerator(limit);

for (size_t i{};i<SIZE;++i)
{
    myArray[i]=  random_number();
}


return 0;
}
```

Link : https://onlinegdb.com/686M8KB1p

Comment: This is not good code. Your PRNG is instantiated every time the function starts. PRNGs need to maintain their state. They also want integers from the look of it; there's no reason to use the `std::uniform_real_distribution` at all.